# What does "class $x \in X$ mean?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I'm working through Escofier's book on Galois Theory, and in several exercises regarding finite fields they use the terminology "class $x \in X$, and I'm not certain what it means. For instance, let $K = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^7 + x^3 + 1)$. It's easy to show that $K$ is a field, but then I'm asked to show that "the class $x \in X$ in $K$ generates $K^*$. Is $X$ simply the set of powers of $x$?

Comment: Most likely $X$ is the class of $x\in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ in $K$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Could you elaborate? What is the class of $x$ in $K$?

Comment: $K$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, so the elements of $K$ are by definition classes of elements of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ modulo $x^7+x^3+1$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Right, thank you. I'm working through several books on Galois Theory to better understand the subject and English isn't my native language. Wasn't familiar with those terms.